# Is there a sample AD & LDAP server for practice?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I am trying to study the connection method to LDAP and AD, but don't have a working AD.

I do have a full working Window 2008 Server.

Is there a sample AD & LDAP server I could use for practice?

Comment: Why not install AD DS into your working server? That seems like the easiest thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can try it for practice

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/windows-server/active-directory-trial.aspx

or you can use an open-source alternative such as:

http://directory.apache.org/

Comment: The first link is dead, FYI

Answer (score 12):

These guys have set up a public, read-only LDAP for testing purposes:

http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server

Comment: 2021-03-18: This server is still up and running. The maybe quickest test is this bash command: `ldapsearch -W -h ldap.forumsys.com -D “uid=tesla,dc=example,dc=com” -b “dc=example,dc=com”` - I have this command from the discussion in the linked webside, below.

Comment: After these many years, it is still running. Great effort and good link. Thanks for posting.

Comment: I think it is no more up and running

Answer (score 1):

zFlex Software now offers a free Online LDAP for developers.  Check out the site at http://www.zflexldapadministrator.com/index.php/blog/82-free-online-ldap